# How to use objectiveC and swift libraries Cocoa Pods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm currently using Swift for an Objective-C project. Previously, I imported those Objective-C frameworks through bridging header since I did not use any Swift pods. But today, I need to use swift libraries such as Alamofire, which means I will need to use_framework! in my Pod File.

However, here comes the problem, after I pod install, and try to run the project on my device, errors jump up! What is even more odds is that everything works fine on simulator.

The errors are mainly about **"Cannot find XX module" / "Cannot find XX local file"** in **objectiveC files.**

I think it must have something to do with "use_frameworks" in cocoa pods. My question is how can I solve this problem? A million thanks beforehand, I have been scratching my head for this the whole day!

Comment: Is `@import XXModule` not working? Posting the entire error and pod file will help us find the answer (so we can reproduce the error)

Comment: Sadly no :(. It seemed to solve the error for importing pods frameworks, but I still have errors when I import local objC files into another objC file. For local import, I tried both @import and #import

Comment: By "local" do you mean Objective-C files in the same project? It should be `#import "LocalFileName.h"` - no modules needed

Comment: Yes, I meant objC files in the same project. I did use #import "LocalFileName.h"...but still said "cannot find xxx"

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but no luck, still not working :(

Comment: @Chenglu how you fixed this, still I am in same issue

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper, I used carthage directly for swift frameworks :p, which does not really solve the issue, but is a quick workaround

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Projects and Delete derived data.  Then do a standard rebuild and it should work fine.  I have run into this a few times when dealing with changing cocoapods.